# my function doesn't want to appears on my render how i can know the render is working?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I used firestore to get my data. My console.log is working and all my data is on my bundle.

```
GetAllTeams = () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found");
        } else {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let Teams = doc._data;
            // console.log(Teams);
            this.state.Teams.push(Teams);
            //console.log(this.state.Teams);
          });
        }
      });
  };
```

then i tried to render my data with my function renderAllTeams :

```
RenderAllTeams = () => {
    return this.state.Teams.map((element) => {
      console.log(element.Activity);
      return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
          <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>{element.Activity}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>{element.City}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: "#5DC1D3" }}>{element.members}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getInfoProfil();
    this.GetAllTeams();
  }
```

And i call my function inside my render

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: "#1F2527", flex: 1 }}>
        <View>{this.RenderAllTeams()}</View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is she doesn't want to appear, i tried to put a background color red on my view to see my function but she seems not here. I also tried to put a console.log on my function renderAllTeams and nothing happened.
Someone has any idea about that ? Did i forget something ?

Comment: Try making it a async function.

Comment: @kundan can you be more specific please ? :)

Comment: This is not how you add/update data to the state: `this.state.Teams.push(Teams);` As far as I can tell, this won't cause a repaint of the UI. You might want to have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: This is a common problem people stumble upon when learning react. Remember that  you are not allowed to mutate the state directly, you cannot simply push an item to an array, instead you should be trying to replace with a new array.. Try using a the concat method or a spread operator.